# facebook sharekit is not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Currently I am working on app where I need to implement sharing of text to facebook and twitter.I used Sharekit twitter is working fine for me but facebook is not working.When I open the facebook action sheet and login to page for sharing then after login screen it sends an alert:

safari can not open this page because address in not valid and after this nothing happens.I tried my best to solve it but did not succeeded.How to solve this?

Comment: Sharekit is not working now. Because facebook is changed its api and now they are using FbConnect for share on facebook. Try to use it.

Comment: Have you set proper application id in `ShareKit` for facebook! First look at this, also you can check for `FBConnect` as suggested by @RahulPatel